# Why does ClassFormatError appear when I call Math.random() more than once per argument-resolution process?

Tags: java, exception, random, method-call, classformaterror

I needed a `.txt` file containing a lot of random integers and doubles - one each per line. I came up with the following code:

```
StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

    int id = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
    double weight = Math.random() * 100;

    info.append(id)
            .append(" ")
            .append(weight)
            .append("\n");

}
Files.write(Paths.get("something.txt"), info.toString().getBytes());
```

And it worked as expected. However, when I tried to 'trim down' the code to this:

```
StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

    info.append((int)(Math.random() * 1000))
            .append(" ")
            .append(Math.random() * 100)
            .append("\n");

}
Files.write(Paths.get("something.txt"), info.toString().getBytes());
```

I received an exception:

> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
>
> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
>   Exception in thread "main"

This is the first time I encounter such a problem. I tried to play a little with the code and realised that the problem is reproduced *if the are more than one call to `Math.random()` per `append` nesting*.

I also tried it with other methods, such as plain old:

```
int foo() {
    return 42;
}
```

in place of `Math.random()` calls. It compiled and executed successfully.

What it is to `Math.random()` that it fails here? Are there any other methods that are unsafe to use like that? What is the official term to describe this behaviour? Is this a common differentiation between methods - whether they can be called in such way? What exactly happens here and how does the exception description relate to it?

EDIT: It might be the case that it's just a IDE/JDK/Configuration bug, but I am unsure about it. I am working with this code in IDE IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition version 2018.1.4.0 paired with jdk1.8.0_161.

Comment: I can't reproduce. I don't get this exception.

Comment: It runs for me.

Comment: Very interesting. Maybe it's fault of my IDE / JDK? I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition v. 2018.1.4.0 and jdk1.8.0_161. Is there any way to confirm that it's an IDE/JDK/Configuration bug?

Comment: I suggest updating IntelliJ and the JDK and most likely it will replace whatever is broken at the moment.